# Using multiple DBContext with different schemas

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm testing the possibility to use multiple DbContext with different schema. 
I've created a test table in 2 different schemas.
Then I've created a DBContext which accepts schema name in the constructor.

I've tried the following test code.
In this way I get the data from the first schema:

```
//FIRST SCHEMA
using (testDbContext db1 = new testDbContext("dbo"))
{
       var firstSchemaResult = (from t0 in db1.xxxtest1
                            select t0).ToList();

}
```

Instead in this way I get the data from the second schema:

```
//SECOND SCHEMA
using (testDbContext db2 = new testDbContext("test"))
{

      var secondSchemaResult = (from t0 in db2.xxxtest1
                            select t0).ToList();
}
```

The strange thing is that if I try to access both schemas, one after another, I get the data just from the first one.
For example:

```
//FIRST SCHEMA
using (testDbContext db1 = new testDbContext("dbo"))
{
       var firstSchemaResult = (from t0 in db1.xxxtest1
                            select t0).ToList();

}

//SECOND SCHEMA
using (testDbContext db2 = new testDbContext("test"))
{

      var secondSchemaResult = (from t0 in db2.xxxtest1
                            select t0).ToList();
}
```

In this way firstSchemaResult and secondSchemaResult get the data both from "dbo" schema.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Can you show us the logic in your testDbContext() constructor? E.g. how is the schema used?

Comment: It is very simple.
This is the constructor:

public testDbContext(string schemaName)
            : base("Default")
        {
            _schemaName = schemaName;
        }

And the following is the onModelCreating method:

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(_schemaName);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

Comment: Even though I have provided below the reason why this happens, I'm struggling with the same issue. I would like multiple instances of the same DbContext, one for each schema. Were you able to solve?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is explained in the official documentation for the [OnModelCreating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#remarks) method:

> Typically, this method is called only once when the first instance of a derived context is created. The model for that context is then cached and is for all further instances of the context in the app domain. This caching can be disabled by setting the ModelCaching property on the given ModelBuilder, but note that this can seriously degrade performance. More control over caching is provided through use of the DbModelBuilder and DbContextFactory classes directly.

**EDITED**

I was able to achieve the desired behavior by implementing a custom IModelCacheKeyFactory as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model), i.e.:

```
public class SchemaBasedModelCacheKeyFactory : IModelCacheKeyFactory
{
    public object Create(DbContext context)
        => context is SqlContext
            ? (context.GetType(), ((SqlContext)context).DefaultSchema)
            : (object)context.GetType();
}
```

where "DefaultSchema" is a property in the DbContext implementation (in my sample, the context of a SQL Server).